# while page is busy in loading, new tab open automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, html

When user submit the form, it take alot of time to load because sending emails after pressing submit button. I want after submitting browser automatically open another tab for user to use. i tried below code but does not work.

```
echo "<script>window.open('Cust_ledger.php?id=$required_name')</script>";
```

Comment: you need to do this before submitting. ie. on click on submit button run a javascript function with `window.open('Cust_ledger.php?id=$required_name')` code

Comment: You could have your PHP send the form response BEFORE it does the rest of its processing and then the user would get control back quickly while the PHP script does its work in the background unless you have some specific reason the user should wait for the PHP to finish.

Answer (score 3):

I'm considering that, you want to open URL in new tab when you Submits a form,

Try this JQuery code, `myForm` is an ID of your form

```
 $("#myForm").submit(function(){
     window.open('Cust_ledger.php?id=$required_name', '_blank');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will do something like this:

Online [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dahanu/edit?html,js,output).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="your_link" href="http://www.google.at" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var yourLink = document.getElementById("your_link").href;
        var newOpenTab = window.open(yourLink, '_blank');
    }, 5000);
});
```